# Cognos 10.2 - How to do a count

Tags: cognos-10

I work for a utility company and I am writing a report where I need to count how many consecutive times a meter has estimated 1, 2, 3, 4 or more times. For example, if a meter estimated in February, and March, had a normal read in April,  then started estimating again in May, June, July and August, then I want to have a column that tells me that the meter estimated 4 consecutive times. Right now it is telling me 6, since it is not stopping at the regular read. HELP!

Comment: I don't think this is possible using Cognos. I spent some time testing some options and I was able to identify consecutive rows by creating a row number data item and using the running-difference function but I was unable to count them independently. I see no way this can be done without some sort of procedural programming which Cognos does not support.